# How can i iterate two django models

Tags: python, django

I have multiple models in my django project. i want to iterate them all so i can access it in django model field. how can i do this?

I have tried zipping them like in my views.py like:

```
inventory = Inventory.objects.all()
header = Header.objects.all()
setup = Setup.objects.all()
revision = Revisions.objects.all()
spec = SpecificationDetails.objects.all()
review = Reviewers.objects.all()

zippedItems = zip(inventory, header, setup, revision, spec, review)
context = {
        'zippedItems':  zippedItems

}
return render(request, 'crud/dashboard.html', context)
```

and in my template file i tried

```
{%for items in zippedItems %}
<td>{{items}}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

but it's not working and i think it did not zipped the objects. any tips on how can i achieve this?

Comment: Did you get an error? It seems. you forgot {%endfor%}

Comment: @AgentNoby Yes I have added the  {%endfor% sorry i forgot to include it in the post

Comment: Try to print `zippedItems` in the console, and show us the result.

Comment: @iri0021 are you sure that all of the 6 querysets (inventory, header, setup, revision, spec, review) contain elements? [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) stops as soon as one of the iterables is empty.

Comment: You could try https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest instead of `zip()`

Comment: @Rvector when I try to print the **zippedItems** in console i get **<zip object at 0x00000221EEA61100>**

Comment: @Ralf i think that's the case because when i make it a list first `zippedItems = list(zip(inventory, header, setup, revision, spec, review))` it returns an empty list `[]` but i have elements inside the querysets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you have similar number of elements for **inventory, header, setup, revision, spec and review**. Please keep in mind that if number of elements are different then it will count the least one.

Please check below `zip` example for better understanding.

**ZIP Example:**

```py
inventory = [1, 2, 3, 4]
header = [5, 6, 7, 8]
setup = [9, 10, 11, 12]
revision = [13, 14, 15, 16]
spec = [17, 18, 19, 20]
review = [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]

zippedItems = zip(inventory, header, setup, revision, spec, review)

for inventory, header, setup, revision, spec, review in zippedItems:
    print(f'inventory: {inventory} - header: {header} - setup: {setup} - revision: {revision} - spec: {spec} - review: {review}')
```

**Output:**

```
inventory: 1 - header: 5 - setup: 9 - revision: 13 - spec: 17 - review: 21
inventory: 2 - header: 6 - setup: 10 - revision: 14 - spec: 18 - review: 22
inventory: 3 - header: 7 - setup: 11 - revision: 15 - spec: 19 - review: 23
inventory: 4 - header: 8 - setup: 12 - revision: 16 - spec: 20 - review: 24
```

> From output you can see that it didn't print the last values of review list as those are not in range of 4.

**You can keep this code as it is:**

```py
inventory = Inventory.objects.all()
header = Header.objects.all()
setup = Setup.objects.all()
revision = Revisions.objects.all()
spec = SpecificationDetails.objects.all()
review = Reviewers.objects.all()

zippedItems = zip(inventory, header, setup, revision, spec, review)
context = {
        'zippedItems':  zippedItems

}
return render(request, 'crud/dashboard.html', context)
```

**You have issue with HTML part. It should be something like this:**

```html
{% for inventory, header, setup, revision, spec, review in zippedItems %}
    {{ forloop.counter }}
    {{ inventory.model_field_name }}
    {{ header.model_field_name }}
    {{ setup.model_field_name }}
    {{ revision.model_field_name }}
    {{ spec.model_field_name }}
    {{ review.model_field_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you still face any issue then let me know. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can first list the queryset and then combine them all together.

```
inventory = list(Inventory.objects.all())
header = list(Header.objects.all())
setup = list(Setup.objects.all())
revision = list(Revisions.objects.all())
spec = list(SpecificationDetails.objects.all())
review = list(Reviewers.objects.all())
iters = inventory + header + setup + revision + spec + review
```

Answer (score 0):

Please User Like this You Convert queryset model to List and then add them in List...the type of all list is list of tuple.
Then,
you have to convert list into zip..
Pass this zip file to pandas dataframe.this will automatic manage your zip file give data in Proper Column Format..

```
inventory = list(Inventory.objects.all())
header = list(Header.objects.all())
setup = list(Setup.objects.all())
revision = list(Revisions.objects.all())
spec = list(SpecificationDetails.objects.all())
review = list(Reviewers.objects.all())
iterates = inventory + header + setup + revision + spec + review

zip_file = list(zip(iterates))

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(zip_file, columns = ['Inventory', 'Header','Setup','Revisoin','Spec','Review'])

context = {
        'df':  df
}
return render(request, 'crud/dashboard.html', df)
```